# Interpolation given a lookup table of f(x, y) = z, if I have an x and z value, how can I interpolate y?

Tags: python, scipy

I have a lookup table that looks as follows. Given an `x` value and `f(x, y)` value, is there a scipy interpolation scheme to query the lookup table to find the y value which is best supported by the data?

[image: lookup_table]

For example, given this data (which is `f(x,y) = 0.1 * x + y`), given:
`x = 1.5`, `f(x,y) = 2`, I should get `y = 1.85`.

[image: data]

Naively I'm thinking I can do 2 separate 1d interpolations -- first on the `x` axis with the given x (let's call it `x*`) to generate a 1d array for `f(x*. y)`, then do another 1d interpolation on the given `f(x, y)` to compute y.

Comment: Can you share an actual example, with a small dataset?

Comment: Updated with a trivial example

Comment: The task can be rewritten as: Find `y` to minimize `abs(f(x, y) - z)` for given `x` and `z`. Maybe scipy provides help to solve this.

Comment: Fair, but then it sounds like an optimization problem when I was hoping to keep it a lightweight simple 1 pass interpolation problem

Comment: In a general, case, you might have multiple matches. What properties of that function can you assume (e.g. monotonicity on both x and y, as it appears in the example)?

Comment: Monotonicity in both x and y, and monotonicity in f(x,y) for a constant x. But since I'm solving this problem using interpolation and not analytically/algebraically, I was wondering if there was some method which would produce *a* good guess by looking around the supplied x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata). For this to work, you need to create the arrays for all the points and then flatten them when you pass them to the function.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

x = np.arange(1, 6)
y = np.arange(1, 6)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = 0.1*X + Y

res = griddata((X.flatten(), Z.flatten()), Y.flatten(), (1.5, 2))
print(res)  # 1.85
```

Comment: Since the data is on the grid, better use interpn, equivalently RegularGridInterpolator. Griddata is for scattered interpolants (triangulation).Naming, I know

Comment: @ev-br I tried those but had issues (related to strictly ascending or descending).